# I created a web app in VS, how do I open it in IIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, web-applications, localhost, iis-8

I have a Web App created in Visual Studios 2012. I need to open it in IIS but am having difficulties. I tried the add website function but the browser address is a localhost:12345 (e.g.) and it won't accept this as the host name. What must I do to open my web app in IIS?
Thanks in advance for any help, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new site on your IIS or change default web site path.
If you chose to change path (simplest solution)

1. Go to IIS manager and point your default website path to your project path
2. In VS2013 go to Project Properties -> Web -> Servers - change IIS Express to Local IIS and add `http://localhost` as Project Url

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just realised I'm working on VS2012.. Could you provide the path for (2) for VS2012? Or is it a different process?

Comment: I do not have 2012, but it should be very similar